# How to set FloatingActionButton border width with Anko

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, anko

I've just switched from **Java** to **Kotlin** and I'm using **Anko** for building **layouts**.

and this is my layout :

```
relativeLayout {

    floatingActionButton {
        imageSource = R.drawable.kotlin_is_amazing
    }.lparams {
        width = wrapContent
        height = wrapContent
    }

}
```

now the question is how to set `app:borderWidth` with Anko ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view has no according `setBorderWidth` method, you can do this through style.

1. Declare a style which will set this parameter.

   ```
   <style name="whatever">
       <item name="app:setBorderWidth">2dp</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Refer this style in an attribute.

   ```
   <attr name="whateverRef" format="reference">@style/whatever</attr>
   ```
3. Pass this attr as `defStyleAttr` to view constructor.

   ```
   FloatingActionButton(context, null, R.attr.whateverRef)
   ```
4. Extend Anko DSL.

   ```
   val whateverFactory = { ctx: Context ->
       FloatingActionButton(ctx, null, R.attr.whateverRef)
   }

   inline fun ViewManager.whateverFab() =
           ankoView(whateverFactory, 0, {})

   inline fun ViewManager.whateverFab(configure: FloatingActionButton.() -> Unit) =
           ankoView(whateverFactory, 0, configure)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually i have switched back to xml layouts